# How to comment out IE conditional comments?

Tags: html, comments

I'm just wondering if it's possible to comment out IE conditional comments themselves (for testing purposes)? The following does not work:

```
<!-- <!--[if IE 7]> some code <![endif]--> -->
```

Thanks in advance! flexx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.

SGML/HTML/XML/XHTML comments cannot be nested.

Comment: so, it's not possible without making them invalid (newtover's suggestion)... thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I think you can just insert something to make them invalid:

```
<!--\[if IE 7]> some code <!\[endif]-->
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!--[if IE 70]> some code <![endif]-->
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I'd use a template systems like Template Toolkit and then Just include or exclude the comment conditionally, based on some variable you could set at runtime.

Template Toolkit http://template-toolkit.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are sending that through a server such as .asp or aspx then of course you could comment that out server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest comments, but you can comment them out by adding an extra `<!--` to the beginning. Your example from above changes from `<!-- <!--[if IE 7]> some code <![endif]--> -->` to `<!-- <!--[if IE 7]> some code <![endif]-->`. Just take out the extra `-->` and it should comment out that pesky conditional.

Tested successful in Firefox 3.5.2 and IE 7.0.5730.13CO